# ¿Cómo agregar los milisegundos que quiero a una hora determinada?

Tags: java, sql-server, date

Tengo la hora `"time":"09:07:07"` que se está guardando en BD como `1970-01-01 09:07:07.000` y deseo agregarle el máximo de milisegundos – 999 – para que aparezca en BD como `1970-01-01 09:07:07.999`.

En Java tengo la siguiente función:

```
public static Date getDateOfTime(String time){
        Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
        date.setTime(new Date());
        String [] horaIniS = time.split(":");
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(horaIniS[0]));
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(horaIniS[1]));
        if(horaIniS.length == 3) {
            date.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(horaIniS[2]));
        }else {
            date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        } 
        date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, MAX_MSEG);
        return date.getTime();
}
```

Siendo `MAX_MSEG = 999`, entonces en B.D guarda: `1970-01-01 09:07:08.000`
y si pongo `MAX_MSEG=998`, entonces en B.D guarda: `1970-01-01 09:07:07.997`

¿Alguien sabe que hago mal para que no se guarde `1970-01-01 09:07:07.999`?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta guardando un año como más actual como 2021 para corroborar la inserción y nos muestras que sucede

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna en el SQL server?

Comment: No haces nada mal. El problema es que tu columna es datetime, y los rangos de intervalo de horas van de 00:00:00 a 23:59:59.997. La precisión es de 0,000, 0.003 o 0.007 segundos. Si quieres utilizar ese tipo de precisión tienes que cambiar a datetime2,.que es lo recomendado por Microsoft, ya que datetime no es un estándar SQL.[datetime](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Correcto, mi columna es de tipo datetime, no sabía el tema de la precisión que comentabas. Muchas gracias!